# How did the first ever software get into the early computers?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, computer-science, cpu-architecture

Early age computers were all mechanical. People had to shift levers to get results. Assemblers/compilers or any code that ever got into computer had to be converted into 0's and 1's. So this needed a converter ? This converter if it was a program, then how did it get into the computer. If this converter was hardware, then what kind of hardware was that ? From the point of being completely mechanical, computers took shape in the form of logic gates. I have been making attempts to understand how at all was the first ever software loaded onto a computer. Today if we need an application to run, we need a platform- the OS. The OS needs hardware. I am sure the OS would not be the first thing that was developed. So, what was that software component that helped to build all these path breaking applications/software that we are using today ? And how was this software component loaded onto the first hardware ? I know, these are too many questions but they will help me get an overall picture.

Comment: I believe are after interested in the [history of programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_programming_languages), which indeed starts with punch cards. It is a programming language upon which the OS is built.

Comment: Not included in that [history of  programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_programming_languages) link is [plugboard programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plugboard) which continued to be used until the 1970's.

Comment: @Nuclearman are you saying Punch cards were kind of programming languages ? They might be since they were instructions to the machine. Then would it be possible to explain the transition from punch cards to Assembly languages that were processed by a processor ? I am sure Punch cards were processed by a kind of processor that wasn't electronic but a mechanical unit.

Comment: A programming language just something designed to communicate instructions to a machine. It doesn't matter if that machine is electronic, mechanical or electromechanical. So yes, punch cards at least technically count as a programming language.

Answer (score 2):

Early electromechanical and electronic computers without nonvolatile code storage had no place to store the boot code - that had to be entered manually during boot. To that end existed a line of toggles which you could set on or off, corresponding with each bit in an instruction code. When the instruction was by flicking these switches "assembled", you pressed a "load" button, which placed the instruction into volatile memory, and pointed to the next memory location, for the next instruction. After you entered the boot loader that way, you let the CPU run across it, hoping that you didn't miss a switch somewhere.

Comment: early assemblers were usually written in machine language, and very simple programs, given that the instruction set of early machines was less complex as those of current machines. Those assembler essentially translated a mnemonic into the opcode, and optionally allowed to enter data in different representations. How they got into the machine was determined by the code loaded from whatever nonvolatile storage was read into the machine by above boot loader. punch cards are not uncommon for the machines of that time.

Comment: "machine language" and "assembly language" distinguished from each other that first is entering a program in binary, octal or hex opcodes, and the latter using the mnemonics as translated by those early assemblers.

Comment: Later electronic computers used core memories which are non-volatile (they retain data even if powered off), and some of those computers had a switch to write protect a region of core for the boot loader, so the boot loader only had to be toggled into the computer if it got overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion was done by humans manually. These people were called "coders" and were usually women. See [this history if ENIAC coders](http://eniacprogrammers.org/)

In the 1970s I did this sort of work myself because I was using very new hardware that did not yet have an assembler. To get the hardware debugged we entered binary using hex keypad on an EEPROM programmer. Translation from assembly code to binary was manual.

Paper (or mylar) tape was another option, but the holes still needed to be punched in binary, and again, the translation was done with human brains and hands.